# Behaviour of bind mounts at upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 - correct?

Tags: upgrade, mount, updatedb

Finally, an almost problem-free update between LTS; at least for me. Thanks a bunch!

There are some minor snags. The one that bothered me most was that all my mounts were inaccessible.
Reason: all directories with removable devices under /media/memyselfI/ at (auto) mount create two directories, one that belongs to root, and one that belongs to me, with a directory name ending at an appended '1'.

Example: I have my data in mounted folder /media/mymyselfI/ABC.
After the restart the auto mount produces two directories:

```
drwx------ 1 root root 118784 Sep 23 14:41 ABC
drwxrwxrwx 1 memyselfI memyselfI 118784 Sep 23 14:41 ABC1
```

ABC is empty, ABC1 contains my data. After some umount, and rmdir of the first as root, everything works once again.

Is this correct, or to be expected update behavour?

Comment: f.y.i., `mlocate` is not anymore by default installed in Ubuntu 22.04. Where is the variable set? Could it have been overridden elsewhere?

Comment: The 'locate' thing has been solved. Thanks anyway!
The non-availability of the devices remains unclear to me.